# ValueError during LogisticRegression

Tags: python, regression

I have an error during Logistic Regression, when I code something like this:

```
logistic_regression= LogisticRegression()
logistic_regression.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred=logistic_regression.predict(X_test)
```

I have an error:

`ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').`

What should I do ?

Comment: Please show your `X_train`, `y_train`. Your input data has an issue like above

Comment: Don't send it N/A or np.inf values

Answer (score 0):

this is a decision you have to take based on the data and the feature which is NaN. imputing this directly with 0 will affect your results.

you can start with these following things.

1. remove those rows, do training
2. if categorical: replace with mode
   if continuous: replace with mean
3. if sequential (like time series) try to replace them with mean of the row above and below.
4. if there are continuous missing try to do interpolation.

so on... please explain more about the data.

Answer (score 0):

It Indicates that your data contain non-numeric data like "NaN", "Null" or "N/A". 
you can handle such data by using following command of pandas:
 1. Fillna(0)
 2. Dropna()